# Query to retrieve top row without using TOP except plain sql

Tags: sql

I   have been asked this question in interview and it seems common question but yet I am unable to get or come up with some solutions so need your help

Can you please tell me method to retrive top 1 row from a table using plain sql and no rownum, rowid, top or limit.

Thanks

Comment: Top 1 row, ordered by what?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Why, it's fine as a question. There's probably a duplicate but not off-topic. Get some pictures from the fireworks with your phone and let us enjoy 4th of July answering silly interview question.

Comment: Not a specific programming question. Off topic, shows no effort.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I disagree, it shows understanding that this is usually done though either TOP or LIMIT or ROWID or some other (usually vendor specific keyword or feature.) He just don't know the answer - with the limitations posed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sample of a query without top.

```
select * from Contests
Where ContestId = (SELECT MAX(ContestId) FROM Contests)
```

Comment: This assumes that the `ContestId` is guaranteed to be unique, otherwise it will return multiple rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using ANSI standard SQL using the `row_number()` function and a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by <however you define the "top" row>) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where t = 1;
```

This assumes that you have some method for ordering that specifies what the "top" row is.  Without an `order by` clause, any row would do.

And I used `*` in the outer query.  Strictly speaking, you would only want to include the columns in the table, excluding `seqnum`.

Comment: Did I misread that the OP mentioned no row number?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO . . . The question says "no rownum, rowid, top or limit".  I see no mention of window functions.

Answer (score 2):

On MS SQL Server you can use the [SET ROWCOUNT n](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx) statement. As in:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1
SELECT * FROM Contests
```

It:

> "Causes SQL Server to stop processing the query after the specified
>   number of rows are returned."

PS: That should be used in case I understood correctly the limit as being the LIMIT clause in MySQL.